# Using Developer Console Query Editor to delete multiple items

Tags: developer-console, delete, bulk-delete, query-editor

I need some assistance with a message I came across while trying to delete multiple items from SF (less than 3K items). I used the query editor to see the items I need to delete but when I select the items to be deleted I get the following message: "Operation cannot be performed - Cannot delete rows if the ID column is not included in the target list". I am very new to using SF and am learning with each new project. I don't know where I should be looking in order to ensure the ID column is included. Please advise or provide resources to research further.

Enterned in Query Editor:
*SELECT PO__c,Factory__c,Retailer__c,CreatedDate
FROM Purchase_Order__c
WHERE
(Factory__c = 'UniqueID' AND Retailer__c = 'UniqueID'AND CreatedDate > 2022-08-29T22:57:04.000+0000 AND CreatedDate < 2022-08-29T23:03:04.000+0000 )*

thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Literally the field called `Id`:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM Purchase_Order__c 
WHERE Factory__c = 'UniqueID' AND 
  Retailer__c = 'UniqueID' AND 
  CreatedDate > 2022-08-29T22:57:04.000+0000 AND 
  CreatedDate < 2022-08-29T23:03:04.000+0000
```

You can include more than that, but the query viewer cannot delete a record without the `Id` field (or edit, for that matter).